# "OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: with space in disk" and there is space

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

Hi I'm having the 'OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: with space in disk' error while I try to create a Docker container. I had the container installed with the jupyter/datascience-notebook image, but I sudendly couldn't connect to the kernel in some notebooks (not all) for the following reason:

`[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/home/jovan/.local/share//jupyter/runtime/kernel-b87ad915-8d97-44ac-80a6-0ab7bd5580bf.json'`

I decided to delete the container  and create it again (terrible mistake) and again had the space on device problem.

The container's creation process is the following:

```
D:\Github\compras-publicas>docker compose run opt bash -c "cd ./src && ./pipeline-join.sh && ./pipeline-clean.sh"
[+] Building 2.5s (6/14)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest                                     1.4s
 => CACHED [ 1/10] FROM docker.io/jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest@sha256:50b773a924586ee721f7729a2dbcb9103a6c  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 37B                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [ 2/10] RUN pip install dbfread                                                                          1.1s
------
 > [ 2/10] RUN pip install dbfread:
#0 0.709 ERROR: Exception:
#0 0.709 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
#0 0.709     status = run_func(*args)
#0 0.709              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
#0 0.709     return func(self, options, args)
#0 0.709            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 333, in run
#0 0.709     build_tracker = self.enter_context(get_build_tracker())
#0 0.709                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/command_context.py", line 27, in enter_context
#0 0.709     return self._main_context.enter_context(context_provider)
#0 0.709            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 505, in enter_context
#0 0.709     result = _enter(cm)
#0 0.709              ^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
#0 0.709     return next(self.gen)
#0 0.709            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/build/build_tracker.py", line 46, in get_build_tracker
#0 0.709     root = ctx.enter_context(TempDirectory(kind="build-tracker")).path
#0 0.709                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/temp_dir.py", line 125, in __init__
#0 0.709     path = self._create(kind)
#0 0.709            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/temp_dir.py", line 164, in _create
#0 0.709     path = os.path.realpath(tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=f"pip-{kind}-"))
#0 0.709                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.709   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/tempfile.py", line 368, in mkdtemp
#0 0.709     _os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
#0 0.709 OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-build-tracker-kcli6ob4'
#0 0.949 WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -c pip install dbfread]: exit code: 2
```

I had to add that I didn't create the creation process (in fact, I'm barely familiar with the cointainers tool, I just limit to work in Python) and the guy who did it don't work here anymore so I his help is limited.

I also would like to attach the output from executing `df -h` :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd        251G  1.8G  237G   1% /
none            5.9G  4.0K  5.9G   1% /mnt/wsl
/dev/sdc        251G  245G     0 100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache
none            5.9G   12K  5.9G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets/host-services
/dev/sdb        251G  120M  239G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-user-distro
/dev/loop0      476M  476M     0 100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
tools           118G   85G   34G  72% /init
none            5.9G  4.0K  5.9G   1% /run
none            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /run/shm
none            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /run/user
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
drivers         118G   85G   34G  72% /usr/lib/wsl/drivers
lib             118G   85G   34G  72% /usr/lib/wsl/lib
drvfs           118G   85G   34G  72% /mnt/c
drvfs           932G  580G  353G  63% /mnt/d
drvfs           932G  652G  280G  70% /mnt/e
```

To be honest, I'm not really sure about what means this info, but I suspect that the problem is related to the `/dev/loop0      476M  476M     0 100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools` line.

Thak you so much for the replies and please try to answer like you'd do to someone who has a very limited knowledge about this topic :)

Comment: Check also `df -i` (it shows the inodes usage). Sometimes it happens to have "no space left on device" error due to missing inodes.

Comment: `/dev/sdc` appears to be full.